# Outputting cookie in Laravel-5/Blade

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have cookie date stored in a serialized array which I would like to access via the Blade template.

If a cookie value is set matching the current field name, then I want to show it.  I am currently using the following code, but I'm not sure how to access the array value.

```
{{{ Cookie::has('myBookingDetails') ? Cookie::get('myBookingDetails') : old('name') }}}
```

The value of the myBookingDetails cookie looks like this:

```
a:4:{s:4:"name";s:13:"Joe Bloggs";s:5:"email";s:29:"joe@domain.co.uk";s:5:"phone";s:11:"0777777777";s:3:"reg";s:6:"123456";}
```

How can I access the "*name*" value via Blade?

Answer (score 0):

The data is serialized. You need to use `unserialize()` function to get the data.

```
$data = unserialize(Cookie::get('myBookingDetails'));

$name = $data['name']
```

Check for existence before use.

Comment: Yes I already tried unserialize(Cookie::get('myBookingDetails')) but then how do I access the array "name"

Comment: Is that done directly in the Blade template or within my controller?  Is there no way to output it directly to the template?

Comment: Better do it on the controller. But you could do it in the template. Try this, may throw a dereferencing error. Couldn't test. `{{{ Cookie::has('myBookingDetails') ? unserialize(Cookie::get('myBookingDetails'))['name'] : old('name') }}}`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if previous answer solved your enigma, but I could give some help.

I fought with a similar case. Seems that in template - in laravel 5.1 - I couldn't access directly to cookies:

`Cookie::get('cookiename')` simply returns null
`cookie('cookiename')` returns a Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie, but `$cookie->getValue()` returns (again) `null`.

The good old `$_COOKIE['cookiename']` returns the right cookie, so you could simply go with `unserialize( $_COOKIE['myBookingDetails'] )['name'];` !

PS: It should be better to handle with cookies in controller and pass a normal variable to the view!